# customizing what files to keep under version control ? [svn]

Tags: svn, version-control

Recently, I checked out a copy of a project, There were multiple source files and a manual makefile based build system.

I did this

```
svn status
No output // meaning . is a working copy

make
// created a lot of *.o files

svn status
No change
```

How come this is possible? This clearly suggests there be some wildcard way to customize 
the files under version control? How can I do that?s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. That files are ignored using svn propset svn:ignore. See documentation: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html
2. Subversion has `global-ignores` setting in configuration file, as mentioned above. By default svn ignores the following types:

`*.o *.lo *.la #*# .*.rej *.rej .*~ *~ .#* .DS_Store.`

Answer (score 2):

The file ~/.subversion/config contains a list of file names
and extensions to ignore in the "global-ignores" setting; *.o is one of those.

Comment: And if there is no `~/.subversion/config` file?

Comment: The defaults are compiled into the Subversion binaries, so they will be in effect even if the config file is not present. If you want to override the defaults, the file needs to be present.